# In Powershell how do "ExpandProperty" of multiple values?

Tags: powershell, foreach, expandoobject

Seems like this should be simple enough.

```
get-childitem -path "E:\Test 1" -Recurse -File | foreach-Object { $fsize=(get-Item $_.FullName).Length ; $hash=(get-FileHash $_.Fullname -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash,Path ); write-host $fsize $hash }
```

This will result in an output like this:

```
18 @{Hash=2FC4C77B6792F3DA856E77486F849105; Path=E:\Test 1\file 1.txt}
```

Now I just want to display file size, file hash, file path.

I know I can use `-ExpandProperty` for a single property but how do I expand for both hash and path?

This works fine for just the Hash:

```
get-childitem -path "E:\Test 1" -Recurse -File | foreach-Object { $fsize=(get-Item $_.FullName).Length ; $hash=(get-FileHash $_.Fullname -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash,Path -ExpandProperty Hash); write-host $fsize $hash }
```

which results in:

```
18 2FC4C77B6792F3DA856E77486F849105
```

But you can't use `-ExpandProperty` with multiple values

```
get-childitem -path "E:\Test 1" -Recurse -File | foreach-Object { $fsize=(get-Item $_.FullName).Length ; $hash=(get-FileHash $_.Fullname -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash,Path -ExpandProperty Hash,Path); write-host $fsize $hash }
```

How can I extract the Path as well so it displays like this?

```
18 2FC4C77B6792F3DA856E77486F849105 E:\Test 1\file 1.txt
```

Thanks in advance for your patience with me and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `Get-Item` to retrieve the file's `Length` - you already have the exact same information from `Get-ChildItem`.

In order to get multiple property values from `Get-FileHash` attached to each file without having to call `Get-FileHash` multiple times for each, you can use `Select-Object` twice in a row to first extract the output from `Get-FileHash`, and then use `-ExpandProperty` against that:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Test 1" -Recurse -File
$lengthAndHashObject = $files |Select Length,@{Name='FileHashOutput';Expression={$_ |Get-FileHash |Select-Object Hash,Path}} 
$finalObjects = $lengthAndHashObject |Select Length -ExpandProperty FileHashOutput

# or as a single pipeline:
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Test 1" -Recurse -File |Select Length,@{Name='FileHashOutput';Expression={$_ |Get-FileHash |Select-Object Hash,Path}} |Select Length -ExpandProperty FileHashOutput
```

---

The `Path` value you get from `Get-FileHash` isn't really necessary either - you already have the same information from the `FullName` property on the file info object and can do just a single pass with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Test 1" -Recurse -File |Select Length,@{Name='Path';Expression='FullName'},@{Name='Hash';Expression={$_ |Get-FileHash |ForEach-Object Hash}}
```